# does using AccessibilityService in android make it a system app?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am making an AccessibilityService to get package name of app where click events are registered. In my manifest do I need to ask for permission for

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
> ```

or inside the service tag, like this :

> ```
>         <service
>         android:name=".ListenToEvents"
>    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
>         </intent-filter>
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
>             android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
>     </service>
> ```

I am guessing I don't need both but if I ask for permission outside the services tag in uses permission the ide tells me this permission will make my app a system app. when the permission is inside the service tag, however, it doesn't raise any such warning.

I do enable the settings for the app after installing. The callback on events is not being called.

first of all I would like to know if my app is a system app which needs to be installed in the system partition of the android phone. any further help will be greatly appreciated. I have already looked at two projects on GitHub but they are too big to sort out the pertinent code. so please help with the code necessary to do the basic task, of lets say listening to a tap event.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you are building your own Accessibility Service, when you execute the app, the service will become present in Settings->Accessibility under 'Services' section. You can then turn on your service and run it on any app you want. Regarding developing an accessibility service, refer to the following,
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service/#2
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service 
For listening to clicks, I suggest going through 'Configuring the scroll button' section of Codelabs and using ACTION_CLICK instead of ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD

Comment: I am doing all of the steps you mentioned but no callback is being called for the touch event. any guesses???

Comment: I am doing all of the steps you mentioned but no callback is being called for the touch event. any guesses??? Also, I have a check just before I call setServiceInfo in the method onServiceConnected(). it too doesn't get called. I read somewhere that onServiceConnected() is called when we manually set the permission in the settings of the phone. but the app is not active at the time, so how will the method get called unless it is a system app, running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify about BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE. You expose that permission in the service to guarantee that only the system can bind to your service. Only the system may use that permission.